# Change custom progress bar color on every rotation

Tags: android, styles, android-progressbar

I am using a custom progress bar which works fine.

I used start, center, end color in code.

But need to change color of progress bar on every rotation. (Every time when progress bar reaches 360 degree rotation, the color has to be changed.)

Please find the code below with single color rotation.

**progressdialog.xml**

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="1"
android:toDegrees="1080" >

<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="20"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <size
        android:height="48dip"
        android:width="48dip" />

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="@color/translucent_red"
        android:centerY="0.50"
        android:endColor="@color/translucent_red"
        android:startColor="#4fff"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

**main_layout.xml**

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressdialog" >
</ProgressBar>
```

Any help would be really thankful.

Comment: it is possible to set the progress bar as per the time ??